# Sql Calculating Averages

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table with 4 columns  DistrictName,TownName,CropName,Pests

I want to count average number of pest in a district  in the same town for a particular crop.

---

### | DistrictName | TownName        | CropName      |Pests |

### |  Rawalpindi  | pindi------------| CIM 506     ---  | 3.3 |

### |  Rawalpindi  | pindi------------| CIM 506     ---  | 3.8 |

### |  Rawalpindi-----  | Muree--------------| CIM 506     ---  | 3.5 |

so for the district name Rawalpindi in the same town name i.e pindi using the same crop i.e CIM 506 i want to calculate the average number of pests there here answers would be (3.3+3.8)/2

This is What I tried so far....

```
SELECT DistrictName,TownName, avg(cast(Pests as float))as pest

  FROM [dw_staging].[dbo].[StagingTable]
  group by TownName
GO
```

Its not working properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to update your group by. Any column you want to select, but won't apply an aggregate function to (e.g avg, sum, max...) has to be part of the grouping:

```
SELECT T.DistrictName, T.TownName, T.CropName, avg(T.pest)
FROM (
    SELECT DistrictName, TownName, CropName, cast(Pests as float) as pest
    FROM [dw_staging].[dbo].[StagingTable]
) as T
group by T.DistrictName, T.TownName, T.CropName
GO
```

Which means, for a given (District, Town, Crop) calculate the Pest average.

Comment: Yes. In your example, Districts contain towns, which then contain crops. So if you want the average pest count for a particular crop within a district town, this query will do that.

Comment: My pest column is of varchar(max)type is there any way to parse it into float in the above query??for some reason ihave to keep it varchar(max)

Comment: Do you get a specific error? You can rewrite as a subquery and do the cast there first - updated my answer to show this.

Comment: Error converting data type nvarchar to float.can u edit the aboce answer if there is any way to do that

Comment: missing "]" - added it back

Comment: updated to a "derived" table - sorry don't have a sqlserver instance in front of me :)

Comment: Invalid column name 'pest  now this error :(.....In the first Line   ihave thoroughly checked the spelling's of the column name..

Answer (score 0):

```
-- Solution #1
SELECT  DistrictName, TownName, CropName,
        AVG(CAST( CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(Pests)=1 THEN Pests END AS FLOAT)) AS AvgPest
FROM    [dw_staging].[dbo].[StagingTable]
GROUP BY DistrictName, TownName, CropName;

-- Solution #2
SELECT  DistrictName, TownName, CropName, AVG(CAST( CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(Pests)=1 THEN Pests END AS FLOAT)) OVER(PARTITION BY DistrictName, TownName, CropName) AS AvgPest
FROM    [dw_staging].[dbo].[StagingTable];
```